# Converting binary file to .p7b format

Tags: binary, cryptography, openssl, certificate, x509

I need to sign a binary `file.bin` and convert it to output `file.p7b` format. 
How to accomplish a task? (Windows OS) What commands should I use with openSSL? (or Certutil.exe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am little confused with your question because file extension .p7b is usually used for PKCS#7 structure that includes only certificates (not signature) and it is more common to use .p7s extension for PKCS#7 structure that includes signature. But never mind it is the file content that matters not the file extension.

You did not specify where are your signing certificate and private key stored so let's just assume that you have your PEM encoded X.509 signing certificate stored in file "signer.cer" and your PEM encoded PKCS#1 private key stored in file "signer.key".

You can use OpenSSL.exe command line utility to sign the file "file.bin" and output the signature stored in DER encoded PKCS#7 structure into the file "file.p7b":

```
openssl.exe smime -sign -binary -in file.bin -signer signer.cer -inkey signer.key -outform DER -out file.p7b
```

You can use following command to verify the signature:

```
openssl.exe smime -verify -binary -inform DER -in file.p7b -content file.bin -noverify > nul
```

See [OpenSSL SMIME module manual](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/smime.html) for more details about individual options.

Comment: thank you, you're right, I was a bit inaccurate in my question: I want to sign binary to .p7b that includes only X.509 DER-encoded signer CVC certificate (signer.cer). Assume the cert is in C:\signer.cer   What should be the command?

Comment: @triwo I don't understand. What do you expect the resulting PKCS#7 structure to contain? You say that you want to get ".p7b that includes only X.509 DER-encoded signer CVC certificate". Then why do you need to sign anything when you don't expect the signature to be present in the resulting PKCS#7? Please describe your use case in more detail.

Comment: The binary already contain the "signer.cer" certificate inside, I want to apply signature to binary.